# Display issue: how to tell it's hardware related?

Tags: display, arch-linux, laptop-display

The issue is that a portion of display on my laptop flashes not-so-dense green dirty things. Like few scattered pixelsflash green lights for few seconds and goes away. It happens unpredictably.
 How can be sure it's hardware related?

I took screenshot with `import` command while it's happening. And view it when it's not. I see clean screenshot. Is that enough evidence that there's some hardware problem? Thanks.

I hope I'm not off topic on this forum.

Comment: We are not a forum.  If the problem exists in multiple operating systems then its not a software problem.

Comment: If you see the distortion it in the BIOS or firmware (go to the setup screen for your BIOS or firmware and see if it's visible there) then it's very likely a hardware issue.

Comment: Does it occur if you hook up an external screen?

Comment: What GPU do you have? This sounds like bump underfill cracking. Does it get worse when the GPU is cold and better when it's hot? Is it getting worse over time?